# Reset primary key counter in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I would like to how can I reset primary key counter in JDBC:Derby from code? I want it reset when I delete database records, but leave tables intact. When I do that, primary key counter does not reset and continue where it ended. I was thinking about something like this

```
ALTER SEQUENCE <tabname>_<id>_seq RESTART WITH 1
```

Will this work? And if yes will it work correctly?

Comment: Why didnt you try this before you post ?

Comment: have you tried searching similar posts in stackoverflow? See this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948325/cleaning-up-oracle-sequences ... may help you

Comment: That depends on your database and your rights to the object. Which database are you using? If it is wise to do is a totally different question again.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm using Derby database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [columnAlteration section](https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html#rrefsqlj81859__rrefsqlj37860) of the ALTER TABLE statement section in the Derby Reference Manual.