# How to Recover an Entire Oracle Schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, navicat, recover

I was using Navicat for Oracle to backup an entire Schema. I mistakenly selected the Execute SQL File instead of the Backup file option and All previous data has been changed/lost. I tried using the Oracle Undo feature but it says the table definition has changed. Please i am not skilled in oracle, i only used it for a project cause it was required so i just use it to store the data. I need all the help i can get right now to recover the entire schema to how it was 24 hours ago else i am so screwed...(forgive my language)

Comment: What did the script you executed do? Did it delete or truncate data, or drop and recreate all the tables? If it dropped them, are the previous versions in the recycle bin (`show recyclebin`, or query `user_recyclebin`)?

Comment: It executed the backup...it dropped, recreated and repopulated...

Comment: Yes @AlexPoole I see them in the recyclebin, please how do i undrop them or make them the default. and is it possible to do multiple undrops at once...cause i have many sequence's that where also affected...

Answer (score 1):

From your description you ran a script that dropped and recreated your tables. As you have flashback enabled and your dropped table is in the recycle bin, you can [use the 'Flashback Drop' feature](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17120/tables011.htm) to get the dropped table back.

Here's an example with a single table:

```
create table t43 (id number);
drop table t43;
create table t43 (id2 number);

show recyclebin;

ORIGINAL NAME                    RECYCLEBIN NAME                OBJECT TYPE               DROP TIME           
-------------------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------- ------------------- 
T43                              BIN$/ILKmnS4b+jgQwEAAH9jKA==$0 TABLE                     2014-06-23:15:38:06
```

If you try to restore the table with the new one still there you get an error:

```
flashback table t43 to before drop;

SQL Error: ORA-38312: original name is used by an existing object
```

You can either rename the restored table:

```
flashback table t43 to before drop rename to t43_restored;
```

... which is useful if you want to keep your new table but be able to refer to the old one; or probably more usefully in your situation rename the new table before restoring:

```
alter table t43 rename to t43_new;

table T43 altered.

flashback table t43 to before drop;

table T43 succeeded.

desc t43

Name Null Type   
---- ---- ------ 
ID        NUMBER
```

You can undrop all of your tables, and as referential constraints still work with tables in the bin you don't have to worry too much about restoring parent tables before child tables, though it's probably neater to do that if you can.

Note that the bit in the documentation about retoring dependent objects - that index names won't be preserved and you'll need to rename them after the restore with `alter index`.

You can't undrop a sequence; those don't go into the recycle bin. If you need to reset a sequence so it doesn't repeat values you already have, you can get the highest value it should hold (from the primary keys on your restored table, say) [and use temporarily change the `increment` value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4948442/266304) to skip over the used numbers.

Comment: I noticed that not all the tables in the Schema are present in the Recycle Bin. Only a few a there...is there any other means i can use to recover all? even if it means the entire database to a previous state. I also noticed the database was in "NOARCHIVE" mode. Is there any harm to that?

Comment: @Richboy - are all the tables your script dropped in there? You only need to restore those; or did it delete/truncate others? If they are not all there, then... is your script dropping any with the `purge` option? With DBA experience you could flashback the entire database but that's even more off-topic, and if tables were purged and you aren't in archive mode that might not help. You said "it executed the backup" - what does that mean, what kind of backup did it do, and can you restore from that instead?

Comment: I used a software Navicat that creates a backup. A sample of the backup it creates can be found here: [SUNSYSTEM.sql](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vlrnh8dboztkzyf/SUNSYSTEM.sql)

I did not see all the tables in the Recycle bin. In other words only a few of the dropped and recreated tables where in the recycle bin...just as if the recycle bin had a storage limit.

Comment: Yes, flashback is limited by available UNDO space and retention parameters. So... why can't you run the Navicat-generated script? Doesn't that contain all the objects and data that were dropped? Am I missing something?

Comment: I ran a previous backup which erased all data which was added/changed from that time till like yesterday. I wanted to backup to a file but i mistakenly selected the feature to execute a backup.